# Что дальше изучать?

Tags: c++, книги

Я изучил основы С++,с синтаксисом я полностью знаком,перерешал больше чем сотню задач,в общем думаю куда дальше двигаться в изучении С++? (Изучал С++ по книге Джесса Либерти С++ за 21 день,правда изучил за 3 месяца и еще с материалами из курсов там много задач было)

Comment: Подобные вопросы уже были. Пользуйтесь поиском.
[Вот здесь][1] например


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/38752/%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-c

Comment: ой не увидел)) спасибо!)

Comment: данный сайт не копия тостера и подобных сайтов, чтобы задавать подобные вопросы. Вам могут помочь в конкретной проблеме по программной части, а не в тематике "что бы мне еще почитать" или "чем бы мне еще заняться".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Углубленно STL. Далее boost. Далее GUI. Системное программирования для Вашей платформы. Можно Qt поучить.

Одновременно пробуем написать самостоятельно свой небольшой проектик.

Comment: спасибо за хороший ответ,хотелось бы тогда еще спросить, а есть ли смысл еще изучить сетевое программирование и базы данных?

Comment: Конечно. Это очень востребовано.

Comment: проблема что я толком не могу найти нормальную книгу по системному программированию,одна есть но она 2000 года возможно там устаревшие методы используют что бы сейчас не изучить то что уже не кто не изучает,может посоветуете какую нибудь книгу? за ранее спасибо за совет.

Comment: Я вообще-то больше под линукс пишу. Здесь уже такие вопросы поднимались, поищи. Если не найдешь, можешь задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: хорошо,спасибо